# What's the easiest way to add CLAHE to Data Augmentation?

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, keras, neural-network, tf.keras

I am new to deep learning and currently attempting to train a classifier with CT-Scans. I am using the Keras ImageDataGenerator to perform on-the-fly augmentation on my images and enable a more robust classifier.

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(shear_range = 0.1,
                                   rotation_range = 15,
                                   zoom_range = 0.15,
                                   width_shift_range = 0.1,
                                   height_shift_range = 0.1,
                                   horizontal_flip = False, 
                                   vertical_flip = False, 
                                   preprocessing_function = preprocess_input)
```

Aside from the random zooming, shifting and shearing as described in the code above, I also want to add random CLAHE application, what's the easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Test this method :

```
def AHE(img):
    img_adapteq = exposure.equalize_adapthist(img, clip_limit=0.03)
    return img_adapteq


datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=30, horizontal_flip=0.5, preprocessing_function=AHE)
```

Happy coding!